# How to check if spark plugs are firing? Coil-on plugs

Tags: toyota, ignition, sparkplugs, diagnostics, rav4

While trying to [diagnose a tricky car not starting problem](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/29219/main-engine-not-firing-after-replacing-fuses-and-transmission-fluid-starter-fan) I was asked to check if the spark plugs were firing at all.

I've found plenty of resources on [inspecting the condition of spark plugs](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17802/how-to-diagnose-a-bad-spark-plug/17804#17804) after removing them, and to do with [diagnosing misfiring spark plugs](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/how-can-i-identify-which-cylinder-is-responsible-for-a-petrol-engine-misfire/9439#9439), but not a test for a simple yes-no, are they firing at all or aren't they.

This is a first generation (1998) Toyota RAV4, which I believe means they are the coil-on type (could be wrong). They're deep set in a straight cylinder.

If possible, I'd like to test if they're firing without removing them, which would require specialist tools I don't have easy access to and might result in me damaging them.

Comment: You should have 2 coil packs on the back side of the engine near the throttle body. Wires run to individual cylinders. I don't know how easy it would be to find locally but you can use an inductance spark tester. http://www.amazon.com/Lisle-19380-Spark-Tester/dp/B0002STS3U.

Comment: @Ben  Good one on the coil pack.  I thought they might be the coil on plug type.  The newer ones are coil on plug.

Comment: @Ben your comment should be an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should have 2 coil packs on the back side of the engine near the throttle body. Wires run to individual cylinders.

I don't know how easy it would be to find locally but you can use an inductance spark tester.

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Lisle-19380-Spark-Tester/dp/B0002STS3U](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002STS3U)

Another  way to see if the coil pack is firing would be to pull a wire out and use either an adjustable spark tester.

[image]

Or take an old plug/pull one from a cylinder insert it into a plug wire and ground the electrode.

[image]
http://autorepair.about.com/od/troubleshooting/ss/coiltest-manual.htm#step2

Comment: You should also answer the title of the question which is different, What I do is make extensions using old plug wires, pull the coil over off and connect it to the plug using the extension, then you can use those tools you posted.

Comment: I couldn't find any tools to do the former. It seems the minimal tools equivalent as employed by these west African mechanics is to pull a spark plug wire out of a spark plug well, stick a screwdriver down the tube and look for a spark when trying to start the engine...